# How can I prevent appendChild() from adding the xmlns=""

Tags: c#, xml, reporting-services, xml-namespaces

Here is a snippet of my code.

```
FilterText = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(FilterTxt.Value.ToString());
               XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
               settings.Indent = true;
               TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("D:\\FilterTest.rdl");
               tw.WriteLine(FilterText);
               tw.Close();
               XmlDocument reportrdl = new XmlDocument();
               reportrdl.Load(ReportFile);
               NMS = reportrdl.NamespaceURI;
               XmlNodeList fieldsnode = reportrdl.GetElementsByTagName("DataSet");
               //XmlElement xoo = reportrdl.CreateElement("Filters", NMS);
               //reportrdl.AppendChild(xoo);
               foreach (XmlNode fields in fieldsnode)
               {
                   // second document to merge (the new Filter File)

                   XmlDocument filterrdl = new XmlDocument();
                   filterrdl.Load("D:\\FilterTest.rdl");

                   XmlNode imported = reportrdl.ImportNode(filterrdl.DocumentElement, true);

                   fields.AppendChild(imported);
                   break;
               }
               //XmlNodeList filtersnode = reportrdl.GetElementsByTagName("Filters");
               //foreach (XmlNode filters in filtersnode)
               //{
               //    filters.Attributes.RemoveNamedItem("xmlns");
               // }
               reportrdl.Save("D:\\NewFilter.rdl");
```

Here is snippet of the rdl file:

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="BOSS">
      <rd:DataSourceID>c6a8409e-71a4-4e96-86ad-b300a5b942c3</rd:DataSourceID>
      <ConnectionProperties>
        <DataProvider>SQL</DataProvider>
        <ConnectString>dats a no no</ConnectString>
        <IntegratedSecurity>true</IntegratedSecurity>
      </ConnectionProperties>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
```

Further on down in this file after `<Query>`, I need to merge in the `<Filters>`

Here is that file:

```
<Filters>
  <Filter>
    <FilterExpression>=Fields!RoleID.Value</FilterExpression>
    <Operator>Equal</Operator>
    <FilterValues>
      <FilterValue>=27</FilterValue>
    </FilterValues>
  </Filter>
</Filters>
```

ends up `<Filters xmlns="">`
instead of `<Filters>`

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure quite what your asking, could you tidy up the question, and give an example of what you are getting and what you want to happen?

Comment: its actually pretty simple I have file that contains XML for a filter and I want to merge it into another xml file (the report rdl). I've found I can do it but when AppendChild adds the node it adds an attribute of xmlns="" which then ends up as <Filters xmlns=""> I simply don't want the xmlns="".

Answer (score 3):

You need to show us samples of the XML of the two files you're trying to merge.

What's probably happening is that in the first file, reportrdl, the `DataSet` elements are under a default namespace declaration other than "". Therefore, every element under them that does not have a namespace prefix and does not override the default namespace declaration will be in the default namespace declared by its ancestor.

But you're importing `Filters` elements that are not in that namespace, and have no prefix. Therefore, **in order to prevent them inheriting a default namespace that does not apply to them, they need to undeclare the default namespace**, which is done using `xmlns=""`.

If the above is not the case, please provide samples of the two XML documents, so we're not trying to do surgery in the dark.

If the above *is* the case, the question back to you is, **why** do you not want the `xmlns=""` in the output? It sounds like it's the correct output. **But maybe you don't want it because you want the imported `Filters` element to be in the same namespace as its parent; in that case, you need to change the namespace of `imported`. Then the namespace declarations will follow.**

Or maybe you want the imported node to be in no namespace, so the output is technically correct already, but you don't like the aesthetics of `xmlns=""`. Or maybe there's a downstream XML consumer that chokes on `xmlns=""` for some reason. Tell us more about your constraints so we can know how to help.

Update:

OK, now we know that

- The elements in the first file are in the reportdefinition namespace, whose URL is `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2009/01/reportdefinition"`. We can tell because the top-level element, `<Report>`, has the default namespace declaration on it: `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com.../reportdefinition"`. This means that for `<Report>` and all descendants, any element with no namespace prefix is considered to be in the reportdefinition namespace.
- The elements in the imported file, like `<Filters>` *should* be in the same reportdefinition namespace. I infer this from the [MS documentation](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/5/7/6575f1c8-4607-48d2-941d-c69622e11c32/RDL_spec_08.pdf), though it's not clear. Much of this documentation is unfortunately awful ... full of [ill-formed XML](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152832%28SQL.90%29.aspx) even!
- However the imported `<Filters>` element and descendants are actually in no namespace (before you import them), because they have no namespace prefix and no default namespace declaration.

So when you import the `<Filters>` element, `AppendChild()` must act to keep it in the same namespace that it's in (i.e. no namespace) - otherwise, it would be like changing its name. `<Filters>` in no namespace is a different element from `<Filters>` in the `reportdefinition` namespace. If `<Filters>` were appended under `<DataSet>` as-is, it would inherit the default namespace declaration from its new ancestor `<Report>` and thereby its namespace would be changed to the reportdefinition namespace.

However, you **do** want it to be in the reportdefinition namespace. The easiest way to accomplish that is to **change your imported file** so that `<Filters>` is *already* in that namespace:

```
<Filters xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition">
  <Filter>
```

Then, AppendChild() will see that `<Filters>` is already in the default namespace of its new ancestors, and won't have to undeclare the default namespace. In fact, it can remove the default namespace declaration on `<Filters>`, which is now redundant.

However, we can't *guarantee* that it will remove it. One important thing to understand about XML namespaces is that what matters is **what namespace each element is in**. It doesn't matter what *prefix* is used to indicate that namespace, nor does it matter where or how many times that namespace prefix (or default namespace) is declared: just so long as each element ends up in the right namespace.

So, whether your imported `<Filters>` element ends up having a default namespace declaration (DND) or not **should not matter** to any legitimate XML consumer. All that matters is that it's in the reportdefinition namespace. If a Microsoft RDL processor chokes on the DND, it means that the processor does not adhere to XML namespace standards.

I would really recommend reading a short tutorial on XML namespaces... They're not that complicated, despite their reputation; they're almost ubiquitous when you work with standardized XML vocabularies; and understanding how the declarations work can save you a lot of headache. [This one's not short](http://www.rpbourret.com/xml/NamespacesFAQ.htm#exec_1) but it's good. I can't recommend the w3schools one because it confuses prefixes with namespaces. :-p

Wow, that got long. I felt like it was necessary, though: we can bail water all day long, but I'd rather plug the leak, which is caused by not understanding how XML namespace declarations work.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I have a namespace in the rdl file that I'm importing the <Filters> for. Here is a snippet of a much larger xml file:

Comment: <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="BOSS">
      <rd:DataSourceID>c6a8409e-71a4-4e96-86ad-b300a5b942c3</rd:DataSourceID>
      <ConnectionProperties>
        <DataProvider>SQL</DataProvider>
        <ConnectString>Data Source=10.254.230.109;Initial Catalog=BOSS</ConnectString>
        <IntegratedSecurity>true</IntegratedSecurity>
      </ConnectionProperties>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>

Comment: Thanks... Can you edit your question and put the snippet there? You can format it much nicer. Do you have a snippet for the `Filters` element and its ancestors? (I gotta go, will be gone for several hours.)

Comment: Thanks for your help XML doesn't cut and paste well for this forum

Comment: <Filters>\n
<Filter>
<FilterExpression>=Fields!RoleID.Value</FilterExpression>
<Operator>Equal</Operator>
<FilterValues>
<FilterValue>=27</FilterValue>
</FilterValues>
</Filter>
</Filters>

Comment: @Lyle, when you put XML in, you have to either make it a code block (select it and press the 010101 button), or if it's within a sentence, surround it with backticks. Thanks for posting your Filters snippet. I edited your question to fix the formatting. I will edit my answer in response.

Comment: @Lyle, I added (a lot) to my answer. Please try what I suggested and let me know if it solved your problem.

Comment: The only problem with that solution is I can't hard code the namespace because these elements are dynamic. both the rdl file and the filter file are being built dynamically. I need to pull the namespace out of the report file programmatically.

Comment: However, your method has solved the problem when I hard code it into the tag

Comment: @Lyle, glad this solved the problem. Please remember to click the check mark to "Accept" the answer.

Comment: sorry your solution is only a half solution?

Comment: @Lyle, sorry, I thought the problem was solved. Can you describe what's missing? You say you can't "hard code" the namespace (presumably of `<Filters>`) because it is being built dynamically. Why is it that your dynamic process can create `<Filters>` but can't specify a namespace for it? How are you building the Filters file? "I need to pull the namespace out of the report file programmatically." Do you mean you need to detect the namespace of `<Report>` programatically? Won't it always be in reportdefinition namespace?

Comment: well if I assume that all my reports are going to be built using visual studio 2005 then "hard coding" http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition as my namespace works fine.

Comment: @Lyle, I think you're implying that the above assumption is not satisfactory. But that's far from explicit, and you haven't answered most of my questions in the previous comment. I'm willing to help, but not willing to waste time shooting in the dark. It's up to you.