# xml document, set attribute question

Tags: c#, xml

Why is it everytime i tried to add a new attribute to a node, it adds an extra attribute `"xmlns="`? any way to prevent this?

```
public void changeProjToAssembly(string projPath,string projRefName)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(projPath);

    XmlNode projectReferenceNode;
    XmlNode itemGroupNode;
    XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

    string s = doc.DocumentElement.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("");
    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("rs", s);

    projectReferenceNode = root.SelectSingleNode("/rs:Project/rs:ItemGroup/rs:ProjectReference[rs:Name='GS_POSLibrary1']", nsmgr);
    itemGroupNode = root.SelectSingleNode("/rs:Project/rs:ItemGroup[rs:ProjectReference/rs:Name='GS_POSLibrary1']", nsmgr);

    XmlElement newCd = doc.CreateElement("Reference");
    newCd.SetAttribute("Include", "dasdsad");           

    newCd.InnerXml = "<HintPath>" + ".//sadssa/asdsad" + "</HintPath>"+
    "<HintPath>" + ".//sadssa/asdsad" + "</HintPath>" +
     "<HintPath>" + ".//sadssa/asdsad" + "</HintPath>";

    itemGroupNode.ReplaceChild(newCd, projectReferenceNode);

    Console.WriteLine("Display the modified XML document....");

    doc.Save(Console.Out);           
}
```

XML:

```
<ItemGroup>
<ProjectReference Include="..\common\librarycomponents\exportdb\GenerateDocLibrary.vbproj">
  <Project>{9B3C9E8B-436B-4A16-87A8-E72CB2FFC6E6}</Project>
  <Name>GS_POSLibrary</Name>
  <Private>False</Private>
</ProjectReference>
<Reference Include="dasdsad" xmlns="">//I only need the Include Atrribute
  <HintPath>.//sadssa/asdsad</HintPath>
  <HintPath>.//sadssa/asdsad</HintPath>
  <HintPath>.//sadssa/asdsad</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Comment: Maybe you could show your code? How do you expect us knowing why your code is adding a `xmlns` attribute without showing your code even if we had a clue? Seems contradictory to me.

Comment: Sorry I have added code now, I am trying to edit the project reference in a vbproj file to be changed as an assembly refrence by directly editing its xml content

Comment: Please show the resulting XML. Also, please say why you care about the xmlns attribute.

Comment: I posted the ouput down below, I dont care about the xmlns atrribute, infact i want it out. I just dont know why it keeps appending that attribute when i create one

Comment: "I dont care about the xmlns atrribute, infact i want it out." John is asking why you want it out. He was leading toward the fact that the `xmlns=""` is just a lexical representation, and the real problem (if any) is deeper. Any XML consumer that chokes on `xmlns=""` per se is broken, so a requirement to get rid of xmlns="" is usually a sign that the asker doesn't understand namespaces.

Comment: @LarsH: in this case, he was creating the element in the wrong namespace. The xmlns was present because he told .NET to put it there - he just didn't know he had told .NET to put it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created your `Reference` element in the empty namespace, not in the `rs` namespace. Try using `doc.CreateElement("Reference", s);`

Comment: Omg it worked, Thank you very much, the xmlns attribute is gone

Comment: @3ggerhappy, I just answered a very similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189348/how-can-i-prevent-appendchild-from-adding-the-xmlns/4189693#4189693 and explained why it was happening the way it was. A little understanding of namespaces will help you avoid these misunderstandings in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are adding an empty namespace into the document here:

```
string s = doc.DocumentElement.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("");
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("rs", s);
```

And then when you append that node it is appending with the namespace that you have added.

Comment: Do you care explaining why that is not it?